# Formatting tooltip in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to make sure that in the tooltip, "(name)" is displayed only after the value along the axis? With the current codes "(name)" is also displayed after string "Series 1:.. (name)".

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return this.points.reduce(function (s, point) {
            return s + '(name)' + '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ' +
                point.y + 'm';
        }, '<b>' + this.x + '</b>');
    },
    shared: true
}
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nsdtf7ah/

Printscreen: http://joxi.ru/Dr8501zTowVWGm

Comment: You need `(name)` after `month`?

Comment: Yes, only after month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `(name)` only after `Month` name then replace `tooltip` with :

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.points.reduce(function (s, point) {
                return s + '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y + 'm';
            }, '<b>' + this.x  + '(name)'+ '</b>');
        },
        shared: true
    },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m4q2sh7t/

If you need 2 `(name)`'s each after `String N` then:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.points.reduce(function (s, point) {
                return s + '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y + 'm'  + '(name)';
            }, '<b>' + this.x+ '</b>');
        },
        shared: true
    },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m4q2sh7t/1/